# Python : force value copy in dictionary within for loop

Tags: python

Here is my code :

```py
sig = {"params":{"weight_curr":{"1M":25, "3M":60}, "weight_rv":{"1M":0.25, "3M":0.6}}}
res= []
tmp = {"tenor": "", "field": "", "signal_parameters":{"weight_curr":0, "weight_rv":0}}
for tenor in ["1M","3M"]:
    tmp["tenor"] = tenor
    tmp["signal_parameters"]["weight_curr"] = sig["params"]["weight_curr"][tenor]
    tmp["signal_parameters"]["weight_rv"] = sig["params"]["weight_rv"][tenor]
    for field in ["a","b"]:
        tmp["field"] = field.upper()
        res.append(tmp.copy())

print(res)
```

I initalize a temporary dictionary `tmp`, which I then fill with different values during the subsequent `for` loop and add a copy of it to my result `res`.

The strings are correct in my result array but the floats are not. All the dictionaries in the resulting array have the same `weight_curr` and `weight_rv` matching the values for the last `tenor`.
I thought adding to the array by doing `tmp.copy()` would solve that issue.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to make a complete copy of a nested structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a copy first:

```
sig = {"params":{"weight_curr":{"1M":25, "3M":60}, "weight_rv":{"1M":0.25, "3M":0.6}}}
res= []
tmp = {"tenor": "", "field": "", "signal_parameters":{"weight_curr":0, "weight_rv":0}}
for tenor in ["1M","3M"]:
    tmp["tenor"] = tenor
    tmp["signal_parameters"]["weight_curr"] = sig["params"]["weight_curr"][tenor]
    tmp["signal_parameters"]["weight_rv"] = sig["params"]["weight_rv"][tenor]
    for field in ["a","b"]:
        tmp_copy = tmp.copy()
        tmp_copy["field"] = field.upper()
        res.append(tmp_copy)
print(res)
```

Request you to show expected output.